# How to modify Djongo ArrayModelField as shown in Django Admin

Tags: django, djongo

I'm experimenting with [Djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/) right now. So far a great project! What I don't like yet is the way ArrayModelField fields are integrated in the Django admin. I am missing something like an add-button. At the moment only one additional empty inline Form is shown for the nested model.
Is there a possibility to add new inline models with an "add-button"?

Comment: You should be using commas to separate two items in an array. It doesn't need any special widget. Sure you can use some js library to create custom input for array.

Comment: Also there is nothing called `ArrayModelField`, you should update the title and description to be little more clear.

Comment: @Saurabh OP is talking about Djongo not Django. In that context, there certainly is an `ArrayModelField`: https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/array-model-field/

Comment: @Gurkenkönig I should have been little more careful. Cheers.